# Remove a specific function from a file with sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

Due to an automatic code scan finding I have to remove the function for self signed certificates from https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/src/ios/CDVFileTransfer.m, lines 838 through 850. So far I have come up to remove these lines by line number

```
sed -i '' -e '838,850d' CDVFileTransfer.m
```

which of course is dangerous if any of the code before changes.

I'm looking for a sed expression that removes everything from the line[(Line 838)](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/src/ios/CDVFileTransfer.m#L838)  beginning with

```
// for self signed certificates
```

to the first line[(Line 850)](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/src/ios/CDVFileTransfer.m#L850) that only has a closing bracket

```
}
```

So something like

```
sed -i '' -e '^"// for self signed certificates",^"}"d' CDVFileTransfer.m
```

Is that possible?

I've tried my luck with regular expressions:

```
sed -i '' -e '#"// for self signed certificates"*^{#' CDVFileTransfer.m
```

but it doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e '/^\/\/ for self signed certificates/,/^}$/d'
```

or

```
sed -e '\@^// for self signed certificates@,/^}$/d' input
```

I'm omitting the `-i` for for clarity, and because it is not available with all versions of sed.  Also, sed is a stream editor.  If you want to edit a file, you should  use `ed` which is the editor for files upon which `sed` is based.  Personal opinion, `-i` is a terrible idea: if you want to overwrite a file, use shell redirections or write a wrapper function.